# How do fractions vectors (from MASS) have error checking?

Tags: r, types, fractions, r-s3

Take the following code that generates a `fractions` vector:

```
> example<-MASS:: as.fractions(c(0.2,0.4))
> example
[1] 1/5 2/5
```

If we were to replace one of these fractions with a string, we get the following error:

```
> example[1]<-"0/1"
Error in floor(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

How does this happen? As far as I was concerned, `fractions` vectors aren't S4 objects and shouldn't have any sort of error checking, so how is `floor(x)` being ran when I'm trying to replace an entry in such a a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fractions` has an S3 `[<-` method:

```
library(MASS)
methods(class = "fractions")
## [1] [            [<-          as.character Math         Ops         
## [6] print        Summary      t           
## see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

and have a look at the R source code at https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/fractions.R

`floor` is called in `.rat` which is called in `fractions` which is called in `[<-.fractions` which is invoked in the `[<-` generic.

```
> example[1] <- "0/1"
Error in floor(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> traceback()
5: matrix(floor(x))
4: .rat(x, cycles, max.denominator)
3: fractions(NextMethod())
2: `[<-.fractions`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = "0/1")
1: `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = "0/1")
```

Comment: That's a shame. I wanted to see if I could easily get it to give 0/1 or 1/1 rather than 0 or 1.